# Exercise: electrostatic force between dielectric and a charge

Tags: forces, electrostatics, dielectric

I have no idea where to start to solve this problem, and haven't found anything similar on the internet. Can someone give me ideas?

The question:

A small neutral dielectric with electric susceptibility χ is placed at distance r very far from a small conductor with total charge Q. It is correct to say that the electrical force between the dielectric and the conductor:

correct answer: has absolute value $|\vec{F}| ∝ \frac{\chi Q^2}{r^5}$

my initial idea:
the dielectric forms a small dipole, whose dipole momentum is proportional to the Electric field generated by the charge Q, thus $1/r^2$. The dipole on itself generates an Electric field falling with $1/r^3$ (as far as I remember). Thus the force felt by the charge Q will be $F=EQ ∝ 1/r^5$. But I'm not confident in this rudimentary explanation. Any proper calculations I can do?